# How do I get the X11 dev files on OS X

Tags: macos, xorg, aptitude, fink

I've been trying to use fink and apt-get but none of the commands (xorg-dev, xlibs-dev, libx11-dev, x-dev etc.) are working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify more?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Check that you have X11 installed in your Utilities folder; if it's missing, install it from the Snow Leopard DVD, the Optional Installs package.  Once that's in place, install Xcode.  It can also be installed from the Snow Leopard DVD, or a newer version can be downloaded from Apple's [Developer](http://developer.apple.com/) site.   Between those two things you should have everything you need to compile X11-based code.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides sources to a large part of Mac OS X (Darwin) [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1066/). `X11libs-40.3` sounds promising.